# How to use LIKE sql wild card in wpdb global variable of wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
<?php   
global $wpdb;   
global $current_user;   
$review_title = isset($_GET['abc'])?$_GET['abc']:'test';
$review_titles = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ch_listing.listingId,organizationName, logoUrl, organizationType,reviewId, reviewTitle,reviewDate FROM ch_listing LEFT JOIN ch_review ON ch_listing.listingId = stakeholderId WHERE (reviewTitle LIKE %s);" '%'.like_escape($review_title).'%')));  
?>
```

Returns null. What is wrong with my code? Is there anyone who can help me on how to use LIKE sql wildcard in `wpdb->get_results` wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
global $current_user;

$review_title =isset($_GET['abc'])?$_GET['abc']:'test'; $review_titles = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT 
        ch_listing.listingId
        ,organizationName
        ,logoUrl
        ,organizationType
        ,reviewId
        ,reviewTitle
        ,reviewDate
 FROM 
        ch_listing
         LEFT JOIN 
            ch_review 
          ON ch_listing.listingId = stakeholderId
 WHERE 
        (reviewTitle LIKE %s);" '%'.like_escape($review_title).'%')));
```

Its hard tell because you have  the `LIKE %s`  where `LIKE '%s'` might help and maybe `LIKE '%%%s%%'`

Best way to trouble shoot this is start talking chunks of code away and see when you start to get results back. Like take away the `WHERE` clause

Comment: $reviewers_title = $wpdb->get_results(  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT chve_users.ID, display_name,userType, reviewId, reviewTitle, reviewDate FROM chve_users RIGHT JOIN ch_review ON chve_users.ID = reviewerId WHERE display_name LIKE  %s",'%'.$reviewer_name.'%'));

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer!
$review_title= "example";
$review_titles = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ch_listing.listingId,organizationName, logoUrl, organizationType,reviewId, reviewTitle,reviewDate FROM ch_listing LEFT JOIN ch_review ON ch_listing.listingId = stakeholderId WHERE reviewTitle LIKE  %s",'%'.$review_title.'%'));

the tricky in the above code is that: $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(argument1,argument2)) accepts two arguments like argument1 and argument2, the first one is a reference two the next one. assume i am passing a string so i should use %s, but if i want to pass argument integer, i should use %d, the lastly the value of the variable may string or integer value.

hope this will fine work for all of you are in problem of using LIKE wildcard in wordpress!!!

thanks too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reviewers_title = $wpdb->get_results(  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT chve_users.ID, display_name,userType, reviewId, reviewTitle, reviewDate FROM chve_users RIGHT JOIN ch_review ON chve_users.ID = reviewerId WHERE display_name LIKE  %s",'%'.$reviewer_name.'%'));
```

works fine